# Open pop up when user changes drop down value in ASP

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I've created a MVC5 application and I use the following code to create a drop down list. It has 2 values like female and male, and the default value is male.
I want to open a popup with a text field whenever the user changes the drop down value, how should I do that ?

The Index code :

```
<td>
            @Html.DropDownListFor(modelItem => item.Genere, item.Genere)
        </td>
```

The model code :

```
  public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Genere
        {
            get
            {
                return new[]
                {
                    new SelectListItem {Value = "M", Text = "Male"},
                    new SelectListItem {Value = "F", Text = "Female"}
                };
            }
        }
```

Update the view code

```
@model IEnumerable<Admin.Models.Admin>
<script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>


<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var dialog = $('#dialog').dialog({
        });


        $('#SystemType').change(function () {
            //if($(this).val()=='F')
            dialog.dialog('open');
        });
    });
</script>
<h3>My APP</h3>


p>
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {

    }


    @*<br style="margin-bottom:240px;" />*@
    @Html.ActionLink("Create", "Create",
        null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "mybtn" })
    <p>

    </p>


    <style type="text/css">
        a.mybtn {
            background: #fa0088;


        }
    </style>

  <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Email)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Geneder)
     </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>


   @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(modelItem => item.Geneder, item.Geneder, new { id = "M" })

                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.ID }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.ID }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.ID })
                </td>

            </tr>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#M').change(function () {
                if ($(this).val() === "F") {
                    dialog.dialog('open');
                }
            });
        });

    </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with help of jQuery. Hope you are already using jQuery in your MVC 5 application

Assuming  in your _layout.cshtml

```
<head>
<script src="@Url.Content("/scripts/jquery.js")" type="text/javascript" />
```

in View

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(modelItem => item.Genere, item.Genere, new {id="ddlGender"})
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#ddlGender').change(function(){
   if($(this).val()==="F")
   {
    //code for opening popup
   }
 });
});
```

Comment: I believe that it is important to add to the answer that you are using jQuery and where the user should place this code.

Comment: Thanks , I new to Jquery so where should I put this code ?after the HTML tag?

Comment: @JeanTehhe, I updated my answer. You need to refer jQuery in your _layout page and the jQuery code i posted it in your view.cshtml

Comment: I try it out and its not working I see the code of the query in the browser ...2.the UI was changed when I put the line in the layout ,why and how to avoid it ? thanks in advance!

Comment: @JeanTehhe, please add your layout code with jQuery script reference in your question

Comment: I forget to close the tag therefore UI was changed ,fixed,now Where should I put the Jquery code in the index.cshteml or Layout ?

Comment: @JeanTehhe, Put my jQuery code in index.cshtml, inside `<script/>`

Comment: when I put it in the view I see the code as -is in the browser.... I put the code right after the html code

Comment: this is the code in the index file and Its not working    @foreach (var item in Model)
{
<tr>
                <td>
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
</td>
 <td>
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email)
             </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(modelItem => item.Genere, item.Gendere, new { id = "ddlGender" })

                    $(document).ready(function(){
                    $('#ddlGender').change(function(){
                    if($(this).val()==="F")
                    {
                    dialog.dialog('open');
}
});
</td>

Comment: Thanks Murali now its compile and I dont have errors but noting happen when I selected female ,any idea what it could be ?

Comment: Btw what is the "ddlGender" ?

Comment: @JeanTehhe, start reading http://www.asp.net/mvc to understand MVC. ddlGender is an id attribute for select

Comment: @JeanTehhe, you specified `new { id = "M" }` but you are referring `#D` in jQuery. What happened?

Answer (score 2):

With jQuery & JQueryUI added to your view, add this code inside your view

Near your `head` tag

```
  <script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js'></script>
  <script src='https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>

 <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
       var  dialog=$('#dialog').dialog({
                                    hide:true
       });


     $('#Genere').change(function(){
       //if($(this).val()=='F')
        dialog.dialog('open');
      });
  });
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
   <!-- ----     ------ -->

 <td>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(modelItem => item.Genere, item.Genere)
    </td>
   <!-- ----     ------ -->
```

and add this html in the end of your view

```
<div id='dialog'><input type='text' id='textb' class='textb'/></div>
```

Comment: Not sure if jquery ui is a part of the mvc.net 5 template by default, but just make sure that you have the jquery ui scripts added to your bundles.

Comment: Thanks Bellash ,where should I pit this code ?inside the      @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.name)
                </td>

Comment: I dont have any body tag Im using table and when I put the code with the div tag I got error :element div cannot be nested to element table ,any idea?

Comment: Ok I see! please paste your entire view code and I can help you editing it. You can update your former question with your view

Comment: I update the post with the relevant code...Thanks in advance!